# Обновление print в одной и той же строке без наложения строк друг на друга

Tags: python, print

Делаю таймер для питона в одну строку с функцией возврата кареты, но проблема в том, что разные выводы накладываются друг на друга и получается что-то типа того, что на фото. Как это можно исправить?

Сам код:

```
import time
 
time_count = 10
 
for i in range(time_count, 0, -1):
    print(('Осталось %d секунд' % i), end="\r")
    time.sleep(1)
print('Пуск!!!')
time.sleep(1)
```

[image: Наложение текста друг на друга].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import time

time_count = 10
print('Пуск!!!')
time.sleep(1)

holder = ''

while time_count:
    time_count -= 1
    holder = ' ' * len(msg := 'Осталось %d секунд' % time_count) + '\r'
    print(holder + msg, end='')
    time.sleep(1)
else:
    print(holder + 'Финиш')
```

Ну или вот так

```py
import time

counter = 10
p_holder = ''


def message(msg: str, eol=''):
    global p_holder
    print(
        '\r' + p_holder + '\r' + msg,
        end=eol
    )
    p_holder = ' ' * len(msg)


print('Старт')

while counter:
    message(
        f'Осталось {counter} секунд'
    )
    time.sleep(1)
    counter -= 1
else:
    message('Финиш', eol='\n')
```

Answer (score 2):

Самое простое и самое неказистое решение - добавить дополнительных пробелов в конец строки, они перекроют предыдущий вывод:

```
import time
 
time_count = 10
 
for i in range(time_count, 0, -1):
    print(('Осталось %d секунд   ' % i), end="\r")
#-----------------------------^^^
    time.sleep(1)
print('Пуск!!!              ')
#-------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Я так сразу и сделал, но у этого решения есть огромные минусы, так как моя строка имеет цветовую оболочку(в коде представленном её нет).